# How do you call a constructor from using getArtefact in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need a list of my domains, and I am getting them by using:

```
def domains = grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")*.clazz
```

In each of my domains is a constructor, I want to do something like this:

```
def item = new domains[0](object)
item.save()
```

essentially making a generic save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to invoke the constructor. I don't know if it is the best way to do it. Example code below:

```
//provides all Domain classes in your project in an ArrayList
//You can also use getArtefact("Domain", "classname")*.clazz to return a subset

def domains = grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")*.clazz

def domain = domains[0].newInstance(object) //Whatever your constructor wants variable: "item" works as well
def domain.save()
```

Got this working thanks to http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2010/06/groovy-goodness-create-class-instance.html